# Why do/don't you think

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I saw this sentence in a comic book:

> Why ***don't you think*** he wants to call her?
>   (Context: A doesn't want
>   to call B. C is asking D's opinion on this issue.)

I wonder if I can use the rewritten version below instead of the original one:

> Why do you think ***he doesn't want*** to call her?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can rewrite the sentence like you have. The original sentence in the comic book, while correct, is slang and is really only ever used in conversation. As the comic book is likely trying to imitate spoken language, the sentence structure that the writers used is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference in meaning between these two versions?

Comment: They mean the same thing.

Comment: I don't think it's right to call this slang. For me it's no more or less correct or idiomatic than the alternative.

Comment: Also, there **is** a difference in meaning. It's subtle, but very important. "Why do you think he doesn't..." implies a stronger conviction / certitude than "why don't you think..."

Comment: I agree with TypelA, there is a difference in meaning when asking what you think versus what you don't think. Also, neither is slang.